# Add Zabbix S.M.A.R.T. monitor to ESXi 5

Tags: vmware-esxi, hard-drive, vmware-esx, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I have a ESXi 5.1 host with 3 Hard Disk (1 SSD, 2 Magnetic) and I want to monitor them, especially for the S.M.A.R.T Data, that is critical and preannunce an HDD break.

Since I'm really unfamiliar with ESXi (i think is red-hat based?) and this is a productive environment, I asked here to get an advise/tutorial/how-to to do this on my system.

How can I install a zabbix S.M.A.R.T data monitor on the ESXi for these disks?

My Disks (i think it doesn't matter) are:

- 1x Intel® SSD 520 Series 240GB http://ark.intel.com/products/66250/
- 2x Seagate Barracuda ST3000DM001 3 TB http://www.seagate.com/it/it/internal-hard-drives/desktop-hard-drives/desktop-hdd/?sku=ST3000DM001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should look for the wbem protocol to monitor your esxi
look at [this plugin](http://www.claudiokuenzler.com/nagios-plugins/check_esxi_hardware.php)

This script is a Nagios plugin to monitor the hardware of ESX and ESXi servers. It can also be used as standalone script to check the hardware - Nagios isn't necessary to run it. The plugin is written in python, so you need to have python installed

usage  : ./check_esxi_hardware.py -H esxi-server-ip -U username -P mypass [-V -i -v -p -I xx]

Though vmware need to recognize the hardware to be able to monitor it.

Comment: Seems good enough to me. I Mark this as solved, since solves my question.